# curl: no matches found

Tags: api, curl

trying to hit a public endpoint that works in the browser(gives json response), But does not in curl.

```
curl https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058
```

It gives the following message

```
no matches found: https://yts.lt/api/v2/list_movies.json?query_term=tt11296058
```

Not sure what could be the issue here, any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It may be due to do with what shell you are using. Try wrapping the URL in single or double quotes as suggested [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/7058#issuecomment-412364730).

Here is the quote from the above link discussing ZSH.

> You need to escape the question mark, otherwise zsh thinks it is a globbing or wildcard character and tries to find files that match it (that's why it says no matches found).